# GRPC::Unavailable: 14:DNS resolution failed when trying to connect python server from ruby client all served on kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, http2, amazon-ecr

I have a Python server and Ruby client. Application was already working since more than a year. But now we are moving to a kubernates. After we moved everything we are receiving following error while we want to access some endpoint on server ..

`GRPC::Unavailable: 14:DNS resolution failed when trying to connect python server from ruby client all served on kubernates`

Since This module is not developed by me I don't have a lot idea about this and not sure what I am missing.following is the code where I want to connect to server ...

```
module CS
  class SD
    def initialize(csm_host: nil)
      @host = host.dup
      if @host.nil?
        @host = ENV['CSM_HOST'] || 'localhost:50051'
      end
      connect!
    end

    def connect!
      @stub = Cs::Csm::SD::Stub.new(@host, :this_channel_is_insecure)
    end

    def some_method(argsuments)
      request = Cs::Csm::SomeRequest.new(arguments)
      @stub.some_function(request)
    end
```

CSM_HOST is address of internal network load balancer where python server is running. Open ports are 50051

Please help me out to fix this issue.

By the way I am using AWS services for kubernates.

Comment: It looks problem with protocol

Comment: My Server side load balancer is a network load balancer and client side is classic load balancer.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your **Kubernetes** cluster ? Do you use a managed solution like **EKS** on **AWS** ? What is the actual domain name your Ruby client tries to cannot to and which cannot be resolved ? Are both Ruby client and Python server deployed as separate `Pods` ?

Comment: Yes I am using EKS. my ruby client and python are on separate pods. Python server is on internal network and so load balancer  is of type 'network'. Ruby client is public app and so load balancer is of type 'classic'. All pods are on same cluster

Comment: Sounds like a simple DNS resolution failure. Are you sure that the hostname of the python server is resolvable from the container the ruby client is running in?

Comment: gRPC doesn't work on classic load balancer. Application load balancer need to be setup for this so that http/2.0 can work on that. We have opted for changing our code so that it doesn't use gRPC.